# My tr border override the table border

Tags: css, border, css-tables

I have the following CSS for my table :

```
table{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
  }
```

I want my table to have a black border and inside, the line are supposed to be separated by a grey border. However the bottom border of the table is overridden by tr and is grey instead of black.

How can I manage to give the priority to the table border against the tr border?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move your bottom border to the top for the `tr`, and set the first `tr` to have no border:

```
table{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr{
    border-top: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
}

tr:first-child{
    border:none;
}
```

[jsFiddle to demonstrate it working](http://jsfiddle.net/T5TGN/1/) (with slightly modified border colours and sizes to help them show up better in the demo)

Note that this solution involves slightly more CSS code than other valid solutions, but has the advantage of better browser compatibility. (`:first-child` is CSS2, whereas `:last-child` is CSS3)

**[EDIT]**

As per OP's comment below: To prevent the cell borders bleeding into the table border, we need to do the following:

- Remove the `border-collapse:collapse`. This is what is making the borders combine together causing the bleeding effect.
- Put the inner borders on the cells (`td`) rather than the rows (`tr`). This is necessary because without `border-collapse`, we can't have borders on the `tr`.
- Add `border-spacing:0` to the table. This closes up the gaps between the `td` elements, which would show up now because the border is on them rather than the `tr`.

Here's the finished code:

```
table{
  border: 4px solid blue;
  border-spacing:0;
}

td{
    border-top: 4px solid red;
}

tr:first-child>td{
    border:none;
}
```

And here's an updated version of the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T5TGN/2/

Comment: i guess there is no way to prevent the red to be on top of the blue (in your jsFiddle).

Comment: Wow, you know your CSS. Thanks! Crazy how something that looks easy needs a ton of tricks.

Comment: For reference : If you have a reset.css or something equivalent, be sure that your table does not heritate a `border-collapse:collapse`
I had to do a `border-collapse:separate;` to make it work.

Comment: *Crazy how something that looks easy needs a ton of tricks.* Yes, so true! Another example of css failing in practice. Why oh why do the cell borders 'win' against the table borders here? Who would want that?

Comment: I haven't gone through this is detail, but I suspect that your edit about bleeding is unnecessary: just change `border:none` to `border:hidden` in your first solution.

Answer (score 5):

use `:not(:last-child)`

```
table{
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:not(:last-child){
 border-bottom: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
}
```

Please see this: http://jsfiddle.net/JSWorld/QmuA9/1/

Comment: +1 correct. However note that this won't work in older browsers (both `:not` and `:last-child` are unsupported in IE8, and `:not` is missing from other old browsers)

Answer (score 1):

Update the table css like the  following

```
table, tr:last-child
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

You can check the [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HbJJD/)

Answer (score 0):

try adding padding-bottom to the tr:

```
tr{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
  }
```